# Stop volumes/partitions from auto-mounting

Tags: linux, mount, startup

I use Lubuntu. My Windows partitions mount every time I use the Linux OS; is there any way to keep them from auto-mounting?

How can I mount a partition when I want to?

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="B9C1-DD76" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0aa163f7-06"
```

Comment: add more detail to your question like, paste the content of fstab file and which partition is windows one.

Comment: @Rakesh.N  Take a look at the question, I added the partition.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the filesystem from being mounted automatically, you may add a line to your `/etc/fstab` file, using e.g. `sudo nano /etc/fstab` or whatever editor you prefer. The line should read

```
UUID=B9C1-DD76 /some-path vfat defaults,noauto,user
```

where `/some-path` means the directory where the filesystem should be mounted. This must exist and be writeable by you. Option `noauto`says the filesystem will not be mounted automatically, and `user` says that normal users are allowed to mount the filesystem.